# What's the best way to downsample a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array, with shape Nx64x64. I would like to downsample it across dimensions 1 and 2 by taking the mean, resulting in a new array with shape Nx8x8.

I have a couple of working implementations, but I feel like there must be a neater way of doing it.

I initially tried to use np.split:

```
def subsample(inparray, n):
    inp = inparray.copy()
    res = np.moveaxis(np.array(np.hsplit(inp, inp.shape[1]/n)), 1, 0)
    res = np.moveaxis(np.array(np.split(res, inp.shape[2]/n, axis=3)), 1, 0)
    res = np.mean(res, axis=(3,4))
    return res
```

I also tried using plain indexing:

```
def subsample2(inparray, n):
    res = np.zeros((inparray.shape[0], n, n))
    lin = np.linspace(0, inparray.shape[1], n+1).astype(int)
    bounds = np.stack((lin[:-1], lin[1:]), axis=-1)

    for i, b in enumerate(bounds):
        for j, b2 in enumerate(bounds):
            res[:, i, j] = np.mean(inparray[:, b[0]:b[1], b2[0]:b2[1]], axis=(1,2))
    return res
```

I had wondered about using itertools.groupby, but it also looked quite involved.

Does anyone know of a clean solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a neat solution in form of the function `block_reduce` in the `scikit-image` module ([link to docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?#block-reduce)).

It has a very simple interface to downsample arrays by applying a function such as `numpy.mean`. The downsampling can be done by different factors for different axes by supplying a tuple with different sizes for the blocks. Here's an example with a 2D array; downsampling only axis 1 by 5 using the mean:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import block_reduce

arr = np.stack((np.arange(1,20), np.arange(20,39)))

# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38]])

arr_reduced = block_reduce(arr, block_size=(1,5), func=np.mean, cval=np.mean(arr))

# array([[ 3. ,  8. , 13. , 17.8],
#        [22. , 27. , 32. , 33. ]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Your reponse was really useful.

Answer (score 4):

Reshape to split the last two axes into two more, such that the latter split ones are of lengths equal to the block sizes, giving us a `5D` array and then use `mean` along the third and fifth axes -

```
BSZ = (8,8)
m,n = a.shape[1:]
out = a.reshape(N,m//BSZ[0],BSZ[0],n//BSZ[1],BSZ[1]).mean(axis=(2,4))
```

Sample run on smaller array with smaller block-size `(2,2)` -

1) Inputs :

```
In [271]: N = 2

In [272]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,6,6))

In [273]: a
Out[273]: 
array([[[3, 1, 8, 7, 8, 2],
        [0, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2],
        [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [8, 3, 0, 2, 8, 0],
        [4, 7, 2, 6, 6, 7],
        [5, 5, 1, 7, 2, 7]],

       [[0, 0, 8, 1, 7, 6],
        [8, 6, 5, 8, 4, 0],
        [0, 3, 7, 7, 6, 1],
        [7, 1, 7, 6, 3, 6],
        [7, 6, 4, 6, 4, 5],
        [4, 2, 0, 2, 6, 2]]])
```

2) Get few output values for manual verification :

```
In [274]: a[0,:2,:2].mean()
Out[274]: 2.5

In [275]: a[0,:2,2:4].mean()
Out[275]: 5.75

In [276]: a[0,:2,4:6].mean()
Out[276]: 5.0

In [277]: a[0,2:4,:2].mean()
Out[277]: 3.5
```

3) Use proposed approach and manually verify :

```
In [278]: BSZ = (2,2)

In [279]: m,n = a.shape[1:]

In [280]: a.reshape(N,m//BSZ[0],BSZ[0],n//BSZ[1],BSZ[1]).mean(axis=(2,4))
Out[280]: 
array([[[ 2.5 ,  5.75,  5.  ],
        [ 3.5 ,  0.75,  2.25],
        [ 5.25,  4.  ,  5.5 ]],

       [[ 3.5 ,  5.5 ,  4.25],
        [ 2.75,  6.75,  4.  ],
        [ 4.75,  3.  ,  4.25]]])
```

Comment: brilliant use of reshape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zoom - scipy.ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom).
This lib allows you to zoom along any of your 3 axis.